# Export data to CSV different row using regex

Tags: regex, csv, powershell-4.0

I used a regular expression to extract a string from a file and export to CSV. I could figure out how to extract each match value to different rows. The result would end up in single cell

```
{  69630e4574ec6798,  78630e4574ec6798,  68630e4574ec6798}
```

I need it to be in different rows in CSV as below:

```
69630e4574ec6798
78630e4574ec6798
68630e4574ec6798
```

```
$Regex = [regex]"\s[a-f0-9]{16}"
Select-Object @{Name="Identity";Expression={$Regex.Matches($_.Textbody)}} |
    Format-Table -Wrap |
    Export-Csv -Path c:\temp\Inbox.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

Details screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

---

**Edit:**

I have been trying to split the data I have in my CSV but I am having difficulty in splitting the output data "id" to next line as they all come in one cell "{56415465456489944,564544654564654,46565465}".
In the screenshot below the first couple lines are the source input and the highlighted lines in the second group is the output that I am trying to get.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Show some data rows.

Answer (score 0):

Change your regular expression so that it has the hexadecimal substrings in a capturing group (to exclude the leading whitespace):

```
$Regex = [regex]"\s([a-f0-9]{16})"
```

then extract the first group from each match:

```
$Regex.Matches($_.Textbody) | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Groups[1].Value
} | Set-Content 'C:\temp\a.txt'
```

Use `Set-Content` rather than `Out-File`, because the latter will create the output file in Unicode format by default whereas the former defaults to ASCII output (both cmdlets allow overriding the default via a parameter `-Encoding`).

---

**Edit:**

To split the data from you `id` column and create individual rows for each ID you could do something like this:

```
Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\input.csv' | ForEach-Object {
  $row = $_
  $row.id -replace '[{}]' -split ',' | ForEach-Object {
    $row | Select-Object -Property *,@{n='id';e={$_}} -ExcludeProperty id
  }
} | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.csv' -NoType
```

Comment: Thanks for answering to my question. I have tried the code but it didn't work as i expected. I have also attached snapshot details  in the question for better understanding.

Comment: It's clearly not possible that you got the output in your screenshot from the sample code I posted. Please update your question with an input sample and a [mcve] that produces the undesired output.

Comment: Ansgar I have tried using the code you provided but remains unsuccessful.  I can't upload the whole code because of compliance and instead have upload the snapshot of what i am trying to get.

Comment: Ansgar Thank you once again for your time. I have tried the code but still it doesn't work.

Comment: Without a [mcve] there's nothing more I can do to help. Good luck.